# CodeChef Runtime Error “NZEC” on Problem “Vaccine Production” (C Language)

Tags: c

I am trying to solve this beginner problem using C language:
https://www.codechef.com/problems/VACCINE1

Would you please give me a hint of what can be wrong with the code below? I am getting the runtime error “NZEC”.

I was suspecting it was a problem with the enum so I replaced it with an in variable, but the problem did not go away.

Here is the solution code in CodeChef page (if you prefer to view like that):
https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/40469687

I am running it in a C++ project in Visual Studio. It runs normally in Visual Studio and the outputs matches the given outputs in the problem statements.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    enum productionStatus {
        CompanyA,
        CompanyB,
        BothCompanies
    } companyProducing;

    short int D1, V1, D2, V2, P, d = 0, day = 0, dayProductionStarts = 0, vaccineNo = 0;
    scanf("%hd %hd %hd %hd %hd", &D1, &V1, &D2, &V2, &P);

    if (D1 < D2) {
        companyProducing = CompanyA;
        day = D1;
    } else if (D1 > D2) {
        companyProducing = CompanyB;
        day = D2;
    } else {
        companyProducing = BothCompanies;
        day = D1;
    }

    if (companyProducing == CompanyA) {
        while (1) {
            vaccineNo += V1;
            if (vaccineNo >= P) {
                d = day;
                break;
            }
            if (day == D2) {
                companyProducing = BothCompanies;
                break;
            }
            day++;
        }
    }

    if (companyProducing == CompanyB) {
        while (1) {
            vaccineNo += V2;
            if (vaccineNo >= P) {
                d = day;
                break;
            }
            if (day == D1) {
                companyProducing = BothCompanies;
                break;
            }
            day++;
        }
    }

    if (companyProducing == BothCompanies) {
        while (1) {
            vaccineNo += (V1 + V2);
            if (vaccineNo >= P) {
                d = day;
                break;
            }
            day++;
        }
    }

    printf("%hd\n", d);
}
```

Comment: Time to drop it into a debugger and see what the internal situation is.

Comment: change the main function to `int main(void)` and add `return 0;` at the end.  NZEC means non-zero exit code

Comment: Totally agree... I am running it on Visual Studio as a C++ project. But I am in trouble with this PC because the antivirus I have installed does not allow me to debug the code. It deletes the exe compiled file. I have not privileges to delete the antivirus. And there is no option to configure white list folders. I hope anybody can figure that out just looking at it.

Comment: M.M You got it. It solved the runtime error. I don't know why Visual Studio is not able to catch that. Maybe it is ok in C++. Thank you very much. Now I am getting an Wrong Answer in one of the subtasks. Let me try to work around that a little. https://www.codechef.com/submit/VACCINE1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Codechef FAQ](https://discuss.codechef.com/t/why-do-i-get-an-nzec/1775)

> NZEC stands for Non Zero Exit Code. For C users, this will be
> generated if your main method does not have a return 0; statement.
> Other languages like Java/C++ could generate this error if they throw
> an exception.

As MM pointed in the comments, change `void main()` to `int main()`
and `return 0` at the end.

Comment: That was exactly the issue. Thank you for answering.